# Android Screen Slide action

Tags: android

I am just starting to learn android java in Android Studio.

And I have bum into a question related to screen slide action.

I wanted to create a screen slide action that allow me to have additional options beside my basic layout's option, after the chose of the additional option I will return to my basic layout.

The perfect example that could represent my idea would be the Google Calculator, when user need advance Math symbol, it has a green layout that show up while user sliding the right's edge to the left, and after user choose one Math Symbol, it will return to its basic layout.

[This is the screen shot of the calculator,photo belong to the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU54n.png)

I am not very good at explaining, I hope you guys understand what I am trying to approach.

Comment: Something like [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)?

Comment: You want to be able to swipe it over the current view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it working using SlidingPaneLayout. Let me know if this works. [image]

XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello SlidingPaneLayout!" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:elevation="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello SlidingPaneLayout!" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SlidingPaneLayout slidingPaneLayout = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.SlidingPanel);
        slidingPaneLayout.setSliderFadeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
        slidingPaneLayout.openPane();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does help a lot, thanks for the helping and the code that you have present it here. Thankyou!

Comment: No problem. If it solved your issue, mark it as solved.

Comment: How do you get the sliding pane to be visible before you slide it out? I've tried and it behaves like a navigation drawer, where you only ever see if if you slide it out. I need it to be partially visible like in the stock calculator app. Thanks!